# If (instance) / implicit boolean conversion on a custom class

Tags: c#, class, operators, overriding

I have the following class:

```
public class InterlockedBool
{
    private int _value;

    public bool Value
    {
        get { return _value > 0; }
        set { System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(ref _value, value ? 1 : 0); }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(InterlockedBool obj1, bool obj2)
    {
        return obj1.Value.Equals(obj2);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(InterlockedBool obj1, bool obj2)
    {
        return !obj1.Value.Equals(obj2);
    }
    public override bool Equals(bool obj)
    {
        return this.Value.Equals(obj);
    }
}
```

My question is: Can I check if Value is true, without `== true`? The operator override works, but can I also use it like so?

```
InterlockedBool ib = new InterlockedBool();
if (ib) { }
```

Instead of (this works, but normally I omit the `== true` in `if` statements.

```
if (ib == true) { }
```

2. And how do I assign it to a value without use `.Value =`?

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: [Implicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) conversion to bool?

Comment: You can use custom conversion operators to convert your type to `bool`.

Comment: You need to look at [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit)

Comment: And what's purpose of this class (out of curiosity)?

Comment: @Evk `Interlocked.Exchange` does not allow a `bool` :)

Comment: Yes but you don't use return value of `Interlocked.Exchange`, and without it it looks useless for bools :)

Comment: @Evk ???. Should I care about the old value?

Comment: In cases where `Interlocked.Exchange` makes sense for bools - you usually do care about old value yes. Assignment to bool is already atomic, and if you care about value visiblity across multiple threads - you can mark bool field as volatile.

Comment: @Evk I read on here somewhere and on blogs too that `volatile` was less appealing than `Interlocked.Exchange`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to be able to convert your object **to** and **from** a boolean

**Implicit Conversion**

Your object to a boolean:

```
public static implicit operator bool(InterlockedBool obj)
{
    return obj.Value;
}
```

Then a boolean to your object:

```
public static implicit operator InterlockedBool(bool obj)
{
    return new InterlockedBool(obj);
}
```

Then you can test it:

```
InterlockedBool test1 = true;
if (test1)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

**Explicit Conversion**

If you want the users of this class to be aware that there is a conversion happening, you can force an explicit cast :

```
public static explicit operator bool(InterlockedBool obj)
{
    return obj.Value;
}

public static explicit operator InterlockedBool(bool obj)
{
    return new InterlockedBool(obj);
}
```

Then you must explicitly cast your objects:

```
InterlockedBool test1 = (InterlockedBool)true;
if ((bool)test1)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

**EDIT (due to OP comment)**

In the conversion from boolean to your object, I call a constructor that you did not mention, here is how I would build it:

```
public InterlockedBool(bool Value)
{
    this.Value = Value;
}
```

Therefore the setting of the value is guranteed thread-safe

Comment: I'm using 2 threads that access `InterlockedBool`. Will returning a new instance of it when converting a `bool` to an `InterlockedBool` cause any problems? (should have made that more clear in the main question)

Comment: why can i never remember this combination of keywords

Answer (score 6):

You can define an implicit conversion to bool :

```
public static implicit operator bool(InterlockedBool obj)
{
    return obj.Value;
}
```